# How do I use a polymorphic many-to-many relationship in Laravel 4.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

As an example for this question, let me use TV shows, Movies, and Actors. Each TV show and movie has multiple actors and every actor is in one or more TV shows and/or Movies. If I set up a polymorphic many-to-many relationship between them it seems that I can query an actor for all of its TV shows and all of its Movies separately but despite all the Googling I can come up with, I haven't found a way to query for a union of all of an actor's TV shows and/or Movies in one collection. Isn't this the usefulness of a many-to-many polymorphic relationship?

If it turns out that this is indeed possible, I will probably add notes including table and model setup to achieve this because I haven't been able to get it working yet. If it isn't possible, can you help me understand the goal of such a relationship because I clearly don't understand it. It seems to me that without this query, I don't gain anything over using two many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will solve your question, but you should be able to get both TV shows and Movies in one collection by using merge

Example Model for demo

```
class actor
{
    public function tv_shows()
    {
        return ...
    }
    public function movies()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```

You can combine them like so:

```
actor::get(1)->movies->merge(actor::get(1)->tv_shows);
```

That will return a single collection of movies and tv shows.

To make life easier create the follow function in your actor class

```
public function tvAndMovies()
{
    return self::movies->merge(self::tv_shows);
}
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: You're right that it doesn't answer the question since you could do that with any two queries and so the purpose of many-to-many polymorphic relationships is still left unexplained but it does give the results I am looking for right now and seems like a reasonably clean way of doing so. Thank you for that!